# Redirect entire www url to non www url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using the following code in htaccess to redirect users from www to non www url of my site.
    
        Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]

#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Right now if someone lands on one of my web pages of my site with www. it redirects them to the main page with a non www.

I want it to redirect them to the same page they were on with it being non www.

Comment: redirect to the same page is should be provided by `$1` (group) in your code, so your code should work as `http://www.example.com/page1` to `http://example.com/page1`

Comment: Can you provide the code as an answer. I tried the answer below and have tried a lot of answers online, but they all redirect back to the home page. I need it to redirect from "www.example.com/example" to "example.com/example" not "example.com/index.php".

Comment: May be your other rules are conflicting with the code above. Could you post your full htaccess?

Comment: I updated the question with the full code.